# NSArray NSDictionary preserve addobject order

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

Is the addObject method of NSArray guaranteed to preserve order? So if I add one object1 and then object2 and then print them, will they always be in order? Is this also true for NSDictionary allValues array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays have guaranteed order, dictionaries do not. Neither do sets.

Comment: Relying on dictionary ordering is particularly nasty because you may get "lucky" and it may *look* right, and then change unexpectedly in a system update when the hashing algorithm changes.

Comment: That's also true of the order in sets.